# How do I get a specific tag from an entire XML file to add to a listbox?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox, nodes

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Tabel>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Cruciatum</Naam>
    <Kills>1000</Kills>
    <Deaths>10</Deaths>
    <KD>100</KD>
  </Member>
</Tabel>
```

When more nodes are added, how can I get the value in the `<Naam>` tags to be added into a listbox?

Note: there isn't a fixed amount of `<Member>` nodes and they all have to have their `<Naam>` elements added into the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim doc = XDocument.Load("members.xml")
    Dim members = From m In doc.Element("Tabel").Elements("Member")
                  Select naam = m.Element("Naam").Value
    For Each member In members
        lstmembers.Items.Add(member)
    Next
```

EDIT:
Changed for VB.NET and op's specifics

Comment: I'ld try it if I knew where to put that 
`System.Xml.Linq`

(I'm in VB2010, not C# :()

Comment: Allright I found where to put it, now the only error I get from that is "Type naam is not defined".

So I have to use `Select naam = m.Element("Naam").Value` . Although now I get the error: "Naam is not a member of string" (in the `lstmembers.items.add(member.naam)` part)

Comment: then do member.naam.ToString()

Comment: Just tried that, Visual Studio doesn't even recognize it as a function and I still get the same error :\

Comment: `Dim doc = XDocument.Load("members.xml")
        Dim members = From m In doc.Element("Tabel").Elements("Member")
                      Select naam = m.Element("Naam").Value
        For Each member In members
            lstmembers.Items.Add(member.naam.tostring())
        Next`